# Google Sheets Apps Script unable to set formula with a query function due to quotations

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My current code is

```
var formulas = "=iferror(QUERY(bridgePriceCase!$A$1:$F,"select F where A = "&"'"&$C2&"'"& " and B = "&$G2&" and C = "&$F2,0),0)"
```

But i get an error that says "Missing ; before statement". I understand it has to do with the quotations used in the 'select' part of the query, but after trying a few solutions, i can't seem to figure out the combination of double quotes and /' to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use it by escaping the double quotes. Please modify to ``var formulas = "=iferror(QUERY(bridgePriceCase!$A$1:$F,\"select F where A = \"&\"'\"&$C2&\"'\"& \" and B = \"&$G2&\" and C = \"&$F2,0),0)"``.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you so much that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 4):

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) provides 2 ways to assign strings:

1. double quotes: `"string"`
2. single quotes: `'string'`

In your case, double quotes are a part of the string, and the quickest way is to use the string inside single quotes:

`var text = 'string ... "" ... string'`

The other way is to use escape symbol:

`var text = "string ... \"\" ... string"`

Please, see more info here:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp