# Can't get a certain formula into sheet using script editor google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Hi all I am haveing a problem geting a formula into google sheet using script editor. I can get one in that doesn´t work but not one that does.

This one will put the formula in but the formula doesn´t work

```
function x1() {
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
ss3.getRange("AF2").setFormula("=IF((AND(OR(I2='YOUR TRIP DWL',I2='MEGA PACK DWL (YT + AA + BONUS)'),L2<=0,AD2<>'')),'Send Email', 'Wait')")
  var lr3 = ss3. getLastRow();
  var filldownrange3 = ss3.getRange(2, 32, lr3-1);
  ss3. getRange("AF2").copyTo(filldownrange3);
}
```

This one shows an Error in script editor but the furmula work in the cells i manually placed in.

```
function x1() {
  var ss3 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
ss3.getRange("AF2").setFormula("=IF(((AND(OR(I2="YOUR TRIP DWL",I2="MEGA PACK DWL (YT + AA + BONUS)"),M2<=0,AA2<>"",AE2<>""))), "Send Email", "Wait")")
  var lr3 = ss3. getLastRow();
  var filldownrange3 = ss3.getRange(2, 32, lr3-1);
  ss3. getRange("AF2").copyTo(filldownrange3);
```

The problem is Line 3 with the formula itself as other fumulas are ok, can anyone shed some light on this, Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF this hels anyone else with the same problem, I have finally solved this problem by changing the double quotes surounding the formula with single quptes and leaving the double quotes inside the formula, so line 4 reads:

```
ss3.getRange("AF2").setFormula('=IF(((AND(OR(I2="YOUR TRIP DWL",I2="MEGA PACK DWL (YT + AA + BONUS)"),M2<=0,AA2<>"",AE2<>""))), "Send Email", "Wait")');
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try your second version with [escaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) of the internal [double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737436/google-sheets-apps-script-unable-to-set-formula-with-a-query-function-due-to-quo).

Comment: Hi pnuts, the fomula doesnt work without the double quotes but does with.